# How to keep quotations when passing arguments in batch?

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to make a python module runner and to have the following command work:

```
runModule.bat module.py "source file.txt"
```

where `runModule.bat` sets up the environment for `module.py` and any further arguments are passed to `module.py`.

I implemented `runModule.bat` looks like this:

```
python _runModule.py %*
```

however, %* gets rid of the quotes and expands my command as `python _runModule.py module.py source file.txt` instead of `python _runModule.py module.py "source file.txt"`. What can I do?

Comment: What? No, it doesn't. http://i.imgur.com/yV8nuPZ.png

Comment: Yes, you're right SomethingDark, I just noticed it. I had a mistake at printing the commandline. :S Maybe I should clear the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something Dark is right, %* keeps the quotes. I was mistaken.